# Is the verb "knew" appropriately used here?

Tags: word-usage

I wonder why the author used it here. Of course, Sims knew what he was doing.

"Before catching the attention of thousands, Sims knew the most important purpose of the video: to teach others to “love themselves and love the art of learning.”"

Source: https://www.huffingtonpost.com/entry/sixth-grade-teachers-class-rap-will-get-you-amped-to-learn_us_59fb536ee4b0415a420a4fa7?section=us_education

Comment: Why do you think "Sims knew the most important purpose of the video" implies he didn't know what he was doing? thinking vs. doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear to me what the sentence means in context; but since (as you pointed out) he must already have known what his purpose was, it must be saying something more. I interpret it as a rather unclear way of saying "His intention was clear to him, and it was ...", but I am not certain.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is correct, since the sentence is in past tense.

> Sims knows what he is doing now.
>
> Sims knew what he was doing yesterday.
>
> Sims knows what he will be doing tomorrow.

Comment: I'm not talking about the tense.

Comment: Then I don't understand why you think the word is used incorrectly.